# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, crash

We experience random system crashes in a WPF application. The application hosts two browser controls and the theory is that this occurs in the underlying internet explorer browser control.

This is the clr call stack when the app crashes:

```
WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)+0x2
WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)+0xb1
WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)+0x49
WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()+0x4b
PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)+0x17
PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)+0x6f
PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)+0x26
PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Application.Run()+0x1b
f2100webhost!Fdc.F2100UI.Client.Webhost.App.Main()+0x54
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception type:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Message:          External component has thrown an exception.
InnerException:   <none>
```

We have generated process dumps that reveal the above, but we can't seem to narrow down the root cause. Any help would be greatly appreciated.